# Current Value for CABasicAnimation

Tags: ios, cabasicanimation

So I animate the path of a circle as such (works perfectly):

```
CGPoint center = CGPointMake([self bounds].size.width/2.0, [self bounds].size.height/2.0);

circle.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:center
                                             radius:radius-13 startAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(0) endAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS([self percentageToAngle:100]) clockwise:NO].CGPath;


circle.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
circle.strokeColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
circle.lineWidth = 27.0;

[self.layer addSublayer:circle];

float currentAngle = [(NSNumber *)[ sublayer valueForKeyPath:@"strokeEnd" ] floatValue];

CABasicAnimation *drawAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];

drawAnimation.duration            = 2.0;
drawAnimation.repeatCount         = 0.0;
drawAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;


drawAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
drawAnimation.toValue   = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];

drawAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];

drawAnimation.delegate = self;
[drawAnimation setValue:kAnimationName forKey:kLayerName];
[circle addAnimation:drawAnimation forKey:kAnimationName];
```

If I stop the animation mid stream, how to I get the current value it's at? Either the angle or just the value between the fromValue and toValue?

Comment: Have you found solution?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Try this when stop animation.

```
float currentRad = [[[circle.layer presentationLayer] valueForKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"] floatValue];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But no, that won't work. I'm not rotating anything around any axis. The animation is drawing on the path which happens to follow the path of the circle. I tried a similar thing with valueForKeyPath:@"strokeEnd" but it's always 1, no matter when I stop the the animation.

Comment: I'm sorry it's missed. I was research a few hours but, I can't figure out.